# Separate mixture of gaussians in Python

Tags: python, statistics, normal-distribution

There is a result of some physical experiment, which can be represented as a histogram `[i, amount_of(i)]`. I suppose that result can be estimated by a mixture of 4 - 6 Gaussian functions.

Is there a package in Python which takes a histogram as an input and returns the mean and variance of each Gaussian distribution in the mixture distribution?

Original data, for example:

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Incidentally, this is a [mixture of gaussians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model) rather than a sum of gaussians (the sum of multiple independent gaussians is also normal). You probably want to use the [PyMix](http://www.pymix.org/pymix/index.php?n=PyMix.Tutorial) library (though I personally haven't used it).

Comment: Due to physical sense of experiment - this should be real sum, not mixture. Also the final goal of maths is to find percentage of each "subpopulation" (area under a gaussian) in whole "population" (area under the curve) - as i understand, mixture model can't answer this question.

Comment: Sure they can, that's what they're for (or rather, they can estimate it- of course there's no way to answer the question unambiguously since there's random chance involved). And unless I'm mistaken, I think you do mean a mixture (except in the sense that a mixture of distributions is like the "sum" of their histograms, one laid on top of another).

Comment: Unless- are these the sum of mutually dependent gaussians?

Comment: In the experiment, each point (there are about 300K of them) should belong to one and only one gaussian. That's why i'm talking about ariphmetical sum of gaussians, not about mixture distribution. Am i wrong?

Comment: Under "each point" i mean "each +1 value on Y-axis". For example, if X near 56, there are 25K "points". Most of this points belong to first gaussian, less - to second gaussian and more less - to third and forth gaussian.

Comment: `each point should belong to one and only one gaussian`- that's exactly what a mixture model is (see my answer below- did it work for you?). You're thinking of a *mixed membership* model, where each point can be in multiple categories at once.

Comment: Yes, i've understand about mixed membership model yesterday and applied your example to my data. Sometimes it works perfectly, some time - ends with error, but this is pymix internal errors.

After all, i think your advice about mixture model is correct, i'm going to try other libs for that (sklearn, for ex.). Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a [mixture of gaussians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model), and can be estimated using an [expectation maximization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) approach (basically, it finds the centers and means of the distribution at the same time as it is estimating how they are mixed together).

This is implemented in the [PyMix](http://www.pymix.org/pymix/) package. Below I generate an example of a mixture of normals, and use PyMix to fit a mixture model to them, including figuring out what you're interested in, which is the size of subpopulations:

```
# requires numpy and PyMix (matplotlib is just for making a histogram)
import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mixture

random.seed(010713)  # to make it reproducible

# create a mixture of normals:
#  1000 from N(0, 1)
#  2000 from N(6, 2)
mix = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0, 1, [1000]),
                      np.random.normal(6, 2, [2000])])

# histogram:
plt.hist(mix, bins=20)
plt.savefig("mixture.pdf")
```

All the above code does is generate and plot the mixture. It looks like this:

[image]

Now to actually use PyMix to figure out what the percentages are:

```
data = mixture.DataSet()
data.fromArray(mix)

# start them off with something arbitrary (probably based on a guess from the figure)
n1 = mixture.NormalDistribution(-1,1)
n2 = mixture.NormalDistribution(1,1)
m = mixture.MixtureModel(2,[0.5,0.5], [n1,n2])

# perform expectation maximization
m.EM(data, 40, .1)
print m
```

The output model of this is:

```
G = 2
p = 1
pi =[ 0.33307859  0.66692141]
compFix = [0, 0]
Component 0:
  ProductDist: 
  Normal:  [0.0360178848449, 1.03018725918]

Component 1:
  ProductDist: 
  Normal:  [5.86848468319, 2.0158608802]
```

Notice it found the two normals quite correctly (one `N(0, 1)` and one `N(6, 2)`, approximately). It also estimated `pi`, which is the fraction in each of the two distributions (you mention in the comments that's what you're most interested in). We had 1000 in the first distribution and 2000 in the second distribution, and it gets the division almost *exactly* right: `[ 0.33307859  0.66692141]`. If you want to get this value directly, do `m.pi`.

A few notes:

- This approach takes a vector of values, not a histogram. It should be easy to convert your data into a 1D vector (that is, turn `[(1.4, 2), (2.6, 3)]` into `[1.4, 1.4, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6]`)
- We had to guess the number of gaussian distributions in advance (it won't figure out a mix of 4 if you ask for a mix of 2).
- We had to put in some initial estimates for the distributions. If you make even remotely reasonable guesses it should converge to the correct estimates.

Comment: thx a lot! sorry, i feel myself like a fool - because of small monitor i see your answer only now.