# Taking out data components to fit a Gaussian

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, gaussian

I am trying to figure out a way to a fit  Gaussian on a data sample such as the plot below. As you can see, to fit the entire I would need to make at least 4 Gaussian fits (3 tall/narrow and 1 short/wide). I was wondering if there is any way to fit such data by taking out the other components, specifically the 2 tall/narrow lines that are shorter than the middle? In that case, I would then only fit a Gaussian for the middle/tall line and the short/wide line.
[image]

Comment: I think you want to fit your data as a sum of Gaussians - take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082171/curve-fitting-by-a-sum-of-gaussian-with-scipy) for exampe.